# how to find multiple files with wildcard expression in objective-c

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, filesystems

How do I get hold of all the *.bmp files (or *.xyz in general) in my Document folder, writing an iPhone 3.0 SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `NSFileManager`'s `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` function. Note that this does *not* traverse subdirectories and `extension` cannot contain a `.`.

```
-(NSArray *)findFiles:(NSString *)extension
{
    NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *item;
    NSArray *contents = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] error:nil];
    for (item in contents)
    {
        if ([[item pathExtension]isEqualToString:extension])
        {
            [matches addObject:item];
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```